# java.lang.NullPointerException at creating new object line

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm trying to use TestNG and Page Object for my Selenium test. But it fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException` error at a line where I'm creating new object of my Page Object Class.

```
public class TestTitle {

    @Test
    public void scenario1() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        FirstPage fp = new FirstPage(driver);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        fp.element.click();
    }
}


public class FirstPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    public FirstPage (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hptl"));

}




FAILED: scenario1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Pages.FirstPage.<init>(FirstPage.java:14)
at Test.TestTitle.scenario1(TestTitle.java:15)
```

FirstPage.java:14 is  `public WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hptl"));`
TestTitle.java:15 is `FirstPage fp = new FirstPage(driver);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public class FirstPage {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebElement element;

    public FirstPage (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.element = driver.findElement(By.id("hptl"));
    }

}
```

Comment: it worked, but is it right to use element in constructor? what if I have hundreds elements like that?

Comment: In your example, `element` depends on `driver`, so it should be initialized like this. If you have hundreds of elements to initialize, you need to use one of the [creational design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)

Comment: I have resolved problem by using `public WebElement element () {
     return driver.findElement(By.id("hptl"));
    }` instead of `public WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hptl"));`